# LibreOffice Calc - do not apostrophe-escape dates when opening a file

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, locale, date-format

I have switched system, and the old system had locale en_DK with reasonable ISO formats, the new one currently has en_US with "imperial" stuff, bad date formats etc. While I try to figure out how to change that, I have a problem opening .ods spreadsheets created in the previous system.

Basically they had all good formatted cells, including numbers and dates, say `14.06.2021` for 14 June 2021. Now when I open them in current LibreOffice Calc, **the application automatically modifies these cells** to be escaped with leading apostroph, e.g. `'14.06.2021`, which is bad, because now these cells are text cells and no longer date cells. How can prevent Calc from automatically modifying the cells? Better, how can I simply use the locale in which a file was saved?

[image]

**Edit:** And how do I find/replace all occurrences of `'foo` with `foo`. I tried find/replace, just entering the apostrophe, but it doesn't find any cell.

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution for this. It involves the “find and replace” function.

1. From the “Edit” menu, choose “Find & Replace.”
2. In the “Find” box, type `^.` (i.e., caret + period).
3. In the “Replace” box, type `&`.
4. You have to do one more thing for this to work. At the bottom of the “Find & Replace” window you’ll see a button that says “More Options.” Click on it, then select the box next to “Regular Expressions.”
5. Now, hit “Replace All” and all of your apostrophes will disappear.

https://www.ryananddebi.com/2009/11/29/remove-apostrophes-before-numbers-in-openoffice-calc/

Answer (score 1):

After changing the system locale, you can select a column, set the correct date format, then run the menu item *Data* » *Text to Columns*.